# Как в пайтоне проверить правильность примера?

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть пример похожий на этот `"5+6=54"` в формате `str`. Надо проверить верно ли решен пример и если ответ верен, написать верен, а если нет, то не верен.

Comment: вы уже что-то успели попробовать сделать ? Покажите ваши попытки.

Comment: да я пробовал через eval но не чего не вышло

Comment: Вам для проверки будет достаточно функций `split` и `eval`, а для вывода результата`if` и `print`.

Comment: @habduzhalilov Покажите ваш код, с которым у вас не вышло, добавьте его в вопрос

Comment: А тебе таки надо только для сложения или для любых действий?

Answer (score 3):

В одну строчку.

```
a = "5+6=11"
print("Верно" if eval(a.replace("=", "==")) else "Не верно")
```

Answer (score 2):

Ладно, раз стали отвечать, приведу и свой вариант:

```
a = "5+6=54"
x,y = a.split('=')
print(('не верен','верен')[eval(x) == eval(y)])
```

Хотя у GrAnd вариант прикольнее )

Comment: Можно ещё круче: `print(('верен','не верен')[len(set(map(eval, a.split("="))))-1])`. :)

Comment: А еще можно вот так `print(eval("__import__('os').system('notepad')"))`

Answer (score 1):

Где-то была тема про калькулятор, где отвечал, но не могу найти. В целом можно использовать парсинг через регулярные выражения. Токенизируем выражение в ключе знак плюс число через `re.findall('([\+\-=])?(\d+)', text)`. Дальше проходим по списку "токенов" и выполняем операции по `if` или можно функции по словарю раскидать.

Ниже вариант для случая суммирования, вычитания и сравнения. Для умножения и деления надо дорабатывать.

```
import re

def check_res(text):
    opers = re.findall('([\+\-=])?(\d+)', text)
    print(opers)
    res = 0
    for line in opers:
        if not line[0]:
            res = int(line[1])
        else:
            if line[0] == '+':
                res += int(line[1])
            elif line[0] == '-':
                res -= int(line[1])
            elif line[0] == '=':
                res = (res == int(line[1]))
                break
    return res

text = '5+6=54'
print(check_res(text))  # False
text = '55-1=54'
print(check_res(text))  # True
```

Вывод:

```
[('', '5'), ('+', '6'), ('=', '54')]
False
[('', '55'), ('-', '1'), ('=', '54')]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ от @GrAnd крутой, но мне кажется более "по питоновски" решить так(ну ещё я постараюсь объяснить как всё работает):

```py
forcheck, answer = input().split('=') #получаем ввод и делим его на выражение и ответ
answer = float(answer) #перводим тип из str в float
result = eval(forcheck) #получаем ответ на выражение
if result == answer: #проверяем ответ
    print('Верно')
else:
    print('Неверно')
```

То же самое но в одну строку(вот это как раз "по питоновски"):

```py
forcheck, answer = input().split('=')
print('Верно' if eval(forcheck)==float(answer) else 'Не верно')
```

Надеюсь, мой ответ был хоть сколько-то полезен)

Answer (score 0):

```
ex = "5+6=64"
if eval(ex.split('=')[0] )== eval(ex.split('=')):
    print("Верно")
else:
    print("Не верно")
```